# Lyx export HTML keeping equations

Tags: lyx, html, export

I have a Lyx document. If I do "File --> Export --> HTML" it produces an HTML, but all inline equations are converted to single text and displayed equations to images. I want to keep the latex code so then I can use Mathjax or similar in the HTML file. Is this possible?

Comment: Is it any better if you try File > Export > LyXHTML?

Comment: Much better indeed. However it converts equations to the unreadable MathML code. I want to keep equations in Latex.

Answer (score 3):

Use `pandoc` to convert latex  to HTML output.

Math rendering in HTML by default will use  Unicode characters when possible, but you can use the --mathjax option to use MathJax to display embedded TeX math in  HTML  output, or alternatively some other, these are the list of options to math rendering:

```
--mathjax
--mathml 
--webtex
--katex
--gladtex
```

See the pandoc manual for more details.

You do not need LyX for this conversion, but for convenience you can configure to make it to do that. Pandoc is already used for Lyx at least in ODT to HTML export, with this configuration:

```
pandoc -s -f odt -o $$o -t latex $$i
```

So, I guess that you need only make a new type of conversion (in Tools, Preferences, File Handling, Converters)  with  some like:

```
pandoc -s -f latex  -o $$o  --mathjax -t html  $$i
```

(Disclaimer: Not tested. Use at your own risk. If this destroys your hard disk, starts the Skynet apocalypses, or worse, it does not work at all, don't look at me.)

Comment: I like this. Will require some fine tuning but I think it can do what I want. Thanks.

Comment: When I try this solution in toy documents it works. However, when I take a real document pandoc always complains about `pandoc: Cannot decode byte '\xed': Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.decodeUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream` where the problematic byte is not always the same.

Comment: Unfortunalety, LyX still use the actually obsolete default  `\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}` so a simple document with "aeíou" causes this error, but in Document>Settings>Language> Encoding you can select "utf8" and to have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` instead (...or you can  delete the above code in latex outputs, since today `inputenc` is already loaded by default by the `utf8` option).

Comment: Why is not this accepted?